# RIght Align text in a Word document

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I'm creating a word document using PowerShell and would like to know if its possible to right align/justify a line of text in my document:

```
##### Create Word Object

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

##### Open Word and make it visible
$Word.Visible = $True
$Document = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Selection = $Word.Selection

##### Place Date information on document in Bold format and right align

$Selection.Font.Bold = 1

##### HOW CAN I RIGHT ALIGN/JUSITY THIS NEXT LINE OF TEXT???

$Selection.TypeText("Date of Transcription: " + $Date)
$Selection.TypeParagraph()
$Selection.TypeParagraph()
$Selection.Font.Bold = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should just be a case of adding

```
$Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2
```

I think 2 is Right Align but don't have a copy of Word to check, if not it's +/- 1 either way.